# Kill all Processes on Unix running older than 10 days as per a pattern matching

Tags: unix

I have a typical case where I have to kill all the processes which are opened and running older than a particular day.

The command I have drafted is somewhat like this

```
ps -eo etime=,pid=,comm=,user=|**awk '/^[0-9]/** && /abcadmin/ {print $2}'|xargs -I{} kill {}
```

The output is as below on which the awk filtering happens.

```
35-23:07:24 3227762 oracl     oracl<br/>
 2-23:07:51 3231800 oracl     oracl<br/>
 7-02:32:20 3235868 oracl     oracl<br/>
   22:59 :52 3240084 oracl     oracl<br/>
69-01:37:23 3244086 oracl     oracl<br/>
 5-23:29:34 3248352 oracl     oracl<br/>
 **5-23:29:34 3268752 abc     abcadmin<br/>
40-21:41:05 3272841 abc       abcadmin<br/>
11-21:41:05 3272842 abc       abcadmin**<br/>
 1-19:48:25 3301506 oracl     oracl<br/>
70-02:00:11 3305648 oracl     oracl<br/>
 2-02:17:39 3321950 oracl     oracl<br/>
      34:47 3326122 sshd         root<br/>
```

I am trying to script the following logic:

1. Take the first column under awk
   e.g. `1-19:48:25
2. Take characters before the first hyphen.
   e.g. in this case it's `1`
3. Check if it's greater than 10 ,
4. If yes then print the pids
5. Delete the pids.

I don't know how to do step 2 & 3 inside awk command.  I'm new to awk scripting; any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this similar question on Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/245105/how-to-kill-all-the-processes-that-have-dates-older-than-today

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do it is to use the `--older-than` option of [killall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall):

> Match only processes that are older (started  before)  the  time
>   specified.   The  time  is specified as a float then a unit. The
>   units are  s,m,h,d,w,M,y  for  seconds,  minutes,  hours,  days,
>   weeks, Months and years respectively.

Comment: I do not find any option like --older-than for killall. I m on Unix box, dont know if it exists there. Thank you for suggestion though, im trying to look for similar commands.

Comment: I'm using a `killall` that comes with the [psmisc](http://psmisc.sourceforge.net/) package.  That option might not be available with other implementations of `killall`.

Comment: I have to do this on the production server, i m not permitted to install some other packages.